Are these ocean currents for my planet plausible?
This is my first attempt at worldbuilding anything at this point. I heavily modelled my first planet after the Earth as my baby steps. I wanted to experiment with how climates on the planet would be different if I tweaked a few variables here and there.
The vertically rotated "Gulf of Mexico" seen below is approximately 15 N to 55 degrees N and 15 degrees W to 51 degrees E. The atmospheric circulation cells and axial tilt (22 degrees) of the planet are pretty much similar to ours. The average temperature of the planet is also 15 degrees Celsius. The star size is also G-type, the planet is 5740 km in radius, and the atmospheric composition is also earth-like. The pressure is 0.96 atm and the rotation is around 26 hours.
The only difference is that this planet is 0.7 Earth masses and 0.9 Earth radius. The red and blue are just my signifiers if coasts are receiving warm or cold currents.

Click for larger version


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do the colors (red, blue, black) have meaning? Can we also see the map of the entire world, so we can get a sense for the major currents? Should we assume that, other than the placement of landmass, we're dealing with terrestrial characteristics (star output, distance from star, size of world, atmospheric composition, etc.)?

I'll edit the question to upload another map. The red and blue are just my signifiers if coasts are receiving warm or cold currents. The star size is also G-type, the planet is 5470 km in radius, anf the atmospheric composition is also earth-like. The pressure is 0.96 atm and the rotation is around 26 hours. Let me know if you need to know more information

Can you please [edit] that and any additional information into the question, Jermaine? Thank you!
